# How to create Service like Windows in Asp.net core?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, windows-services, asp.net-core-hosted-services, ihostedservice

There is a different way to create service in Aspnet core. **IHostedService** interface is used to create services like **Windows Service**.

Use **IHostedService** in the WebApi project and deploy it as a Web project. As soon as the API project will start your service gets started.

**Service Code:**
Create a Class **MyHostedService.cs** and put the below code into this class.

**Class**

```
public class MyHostedService:IHostedService 
{
  private Timer _timer { get; set; }
}
```

**Start**

```
public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{ 
    _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(OrderExportPurgeTimeInterval));
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

**Stop**

```
public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    _timer ?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

**Your DoWork**

```
private void DoWork(object state)
{
    bool hasLock = false;
    try
      {
        Monitor.TryEnter(_locker, ref hasLock);
        if (hasLock)
        {
            PurgeProcessor.ProcessPurge().Wait();
        }
      }
      finally
      {
          if (hasLock) Monitor.Exit(_locker);
      }
 }
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddHostedService<MyHostedService>();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Create WebAPi as Service in Aspnet core